# Screen turns off after inactivity

Tags: 12.10, laptop, display, power-management

My screen turns off if I'm inactive for some time, even though I disabled the setting. It happens on battery as well as on AC power.

My Brightness and Lock Settings:

[image: My Brightness and Lock Settings]

My Power Settings:

[image: My Power Settings]

Does anybody what I forgot or how to fix this?

I already looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70633/how-to-disable-screen-dimming-after-inactivity-when-this-is-already-disabled-at) question, but I don't want to use Caffeine.

**EDIT**

I've watched the problem for some time now and found that it is not really reproducible. It happens very seldomly by now, but when it happens I can't find out what it is triggered by. Sometimes it's on battery and sometimes not (although I have the feeling it happens more often on battery). Also the battery loading state doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/216783/ubuntu-12-10-turn-screen-off-when-inactive-for-never-still-turns-off

Comment: Not a duplicate. My screen really turns of and not just black.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the reason, the screen is not turned off but a blank screensaver starts.

I don't know why Screensaver disappeared from system settings. I have installed xscreensaver package and deactivated it manually (set Mode = Disable Screen Saver).

Tell me if it will work for you.

Comment: As I have written in the comments, the screen doesn't go blank but turns of. Is that the case with your solution?

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks :)