# Ubuntu 12.10 "Turn screen off when inactive for: Never" still turns off

Tags: 12.10, display, screen, power-management

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10, my screen still goes off after about ten minutes.  I've been to the Brightness and Lock control panel.  The `Turn screen off when inactive for:` setting is set to `Never`.

I've been through the `dconf` editor searching for `power`, `screen`, and `idle` changing parameters.  This doesn't seem to have any effect on the display timeout.

Here's one more interesting thing, the screen doesn't go off, it just goes black.  The back lighting is still on, and all the pixels are black.

When it goes black, it does a very pleasant quick dim to black.
Similarly, it quickly un-dim's after a key press, mouse movement, or mouse click.

Answer (score 34):

There are multiple different layers, that influence the behavior of the monitor. To completely disable any suspension of the monitor you need to disable it in every of those layers:

**1. layer: virtual consoles**

Sets  the  interval  of  inactivity, in minutes, after which the screen will be automatically blanked:

```
setterm -blank 0
```

Sets  the  VESA powerdown interval in minutes:

```
setterm -powerdown 0
```

**2. layer: X**

Turn the screen saver function off. The s option lets you set the screen saver parameters.

```
xset s off
```

Disable [DPMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) if enabled:

```
xset -dpms
```

To find out which values are set type `xset -q` in a terminal. A part of the output should look like this:

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
```

and this:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

**3. layer: Last but not least; the application layer (XScreenSaver)**

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

Choose <kbd>Disable Screen Saver</kbd>:

[image: xscreensaver]

And deactivate screensaver in System Settings -> Brightness & Lock (depends on your desktop environment):

Turn screen of when inactive for: <kbd>Never</kbd>

[image: Brightness & Lock]

Comment: for me, the devil was `dpms`.

Comment: Its 2017 yet this answer made my day!.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 6):

I just ran `sudo xset s off` from a terminal and it may be fixed.

Comment: @Dusty, dont keep us in  suspense.  Maybe fixed or is fixed?

Comment: I fixed this by `xset s 0 0` - not sure if this is equivalent.

Comment: This suggestion did work for me, but I also had to uncheck the 'Dim screen to save power' checkbox in the 'Brightness and lock' settings.

Comment: ... err which suggestion worked for you Zoltan? `xset s off` or `xset s 0 0`... This is a really confusing question/answer page.

Comment: This one answer (i.e. "sudo xset s off") worked for me. I had also previously uninstalled gnome-screensaver, which didn't change a thing. (so I'm not sure whether one needs to do both things but I don't think so).

Comment: It would be nice if Dusty or anyone else could explain a little bit the rationale behind this fix, i.e. what this command does exactly and why such a settings is not accessible from Ubuntu's System Settings (well, actually there can't be any good reason for the latter)

Comment: Note: This is a temporary fix that reverts after boot

Answer (score 3):

There is a checkbox in "System Settings" -> "Brightness And Lock" screen whose label is "Dim screen to save power". You must uncheck it.

Comment: There isn't such option at my ubuntu 12.10 :/

Comment: It still goes black, exactly as described in question - I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 and Gnome 3 (it worked fine on Unity)

Comment: You should apply this advice in conjunction with the top rated answer, i.e. execute `sudo xset s off`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by chaos is very informative. However, even after following those instructions, I still had this problem intermittently. There is some sort of background process or settings manager that keeps resetting the screensaver, no matter what I do.

I've found a brute-force solution. Just add a line to your crontab to turn off DPMS and the screensaver *every single minute*. Ugly, but effective.

Type this at the terminal

```
crontab -e
```

And then add the following lines at the bottom of the file

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 xset -dpms
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 xset s off
```

You can also comment these lines out by prepending a '#' when you want to re-enable the screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

**In Ubuntu 12.10, If you have KDE as the windowing manager:**

Disable monitor dimming and energy saving tool:

1. Click System Settings.
2. In the "Hardware" tab choose "Power Management"
3. Choose "Energy saving settings"

there are two checkboxes:  `Dim Display` and `Screen Energy Saving`.   Make sure those are unchecked.

**In Ubuntu 12.10, If you are using the default unity windowing manager:**

1. Click System Settings.
2. In the "Hardware" tab choose "Power"
3. Click the link: "Brightness settings"
4. There is a dropdown called: "Turn screen off when inactive for"

Set the dropdown to 'Never'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gsettings** for enabling and disabling monitor from going to sleep:

- Disable turning off screen

  > gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
- Enable turning off screen with 5 min delay

  > gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 300

source : https://askubuntu.com/a/788456/88543

Answer (score 0):

```
xset -dpms
```

It solved this issue in Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
[Reference](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337399)