# System not sleeping at lock screen

Tags: suspend

When sitting at the lock screen, such as upon initial boot, the system never goes to sleep.  However, once logged in sleep works just fine.

Should it be going to sleep at the lock screen?  If so, how do I go about figuring out what is preventing sleep?

Running 16.04 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Before you login, your login manager session runs as the system user with his settings. Once you are logged in, you get your settings and your sleep setup. Look for ways to set the session defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FredFoo's comment for getting me on the right track, and the post at [How to let screen time out on sign in screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369230/how-to-let-screen-time-out-on-sign-in-screen), I was able to figure out that the user for the login screen is `lightdm`.

Run this to find all of the lightdm user's power settings:

```
sudo -H -u lightdm dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

Then run this similar command to see the current user's power settings:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

Based on the above I was able to figure out that the setting I needed was `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`, which was set to 0 for the `lightdm` user but was set to 300 for my personal user.

Then I ran:

```
sudo -H -u lightdm dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
```

to set the same timeout, restarted, and everything is now working as expected.